# How can i show sub-category in category into data collapse, Using Djagno

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to show subcategory in category into data collapse using django. As I am a noob developer that's why i can't understand the logic. Category and Sub-Category model is,

category.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

subcategory.py

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I wanna show those value using generic.ListView

views.py

```
class PagetListView(ListView):
    model = ModelName
    template_name = 'template.html'
    context_object_name = 'main_content'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['category_list'] = Category.objects.all()
        # context['sub_category'] =  
        return context
```

I wanna show just like this,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `category` is an instance of Category model

> category.subcategory_set.all()

will give you query-set of all subcategories fo a perticular category

So u just need to iterate over all the categories and get subcategories for each

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. Its nothing just a logic with if else.

```
<div>
{% for category in category_list %}
<div id="headingTwo">
<h5 class="mb-0">
<button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ category.category }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
{{ category.category }}
</button>
</h5>
</div>
<div id="{{ category.category }}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
<div class="sub-category">
{% for sub_cat in sub_category %}
{% if sub_cat.category == category %}
<a href="{{ sub_cat.get_absolute_url }}" class="">{{ sub_cat.sub_category }}</a><br/>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```